# write unicode objects from loop to list in Python

Tags: python, list, unicode, append

I have a loop that returns me unicode objects:

```
for i in X:
print i

Output:  

  A
  B
  C
  ...
  Z
```

How can I make a list of these objects to get the folloving?

```
['A', 'B', ..., 'Z']
```

If they were numbers, i'd do

```
for i in X:
y=[]
i.append(y)
```

but here i get the error

```
AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'append'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looping through a variable, you already know it is an iterable, such as a generator or list. First, you need to tell us the type of the `x` variable in your statement.

If your expected output is a list and `x` is not one, simply call the `list` function:

```
new_list = list(x)
```

If it's necessary that you build the list in a loop for some reason, you should call the `append` function on a previously created list--not an item, as you do in your example:

```
new_list = []
for i in x:
    new_list.append(i)
print (new_list)
```

Comment: but that's what i m doing before getting the error :(

Comment: @Polly No you're not. You are doing `i.append(new_list)` instead of `new_list.append(i)`

Comment: No it's not: your code is unindented, first of all, and second you are declaring an (unused) `y` variable *inside* the loop and then appending to the item `i`, not the list. Notice that I wrote `new_list.append`, not `i.append`

Answer (score 0):

try this:

`output_list = [y for y in x]`

in your loop:

```
for i in X:
    i.append(X)
```

it takes each item in `X`, which are unicode chars, and tries to append the whole `X` object to it.

I think what you're wanting to do is like this:

```
l = []
for i in X:
    l.append(i)
print l
```

but this can be accomplished with simple list comprehension showed above.

Comment: This is long for `output_list = list(x)`